# requests.html .find method returns empty array (css selector has no problem)

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the opensea's rankings page.

The code below returns the right HTML Element object.
But the next one returns an empty array

```
# this one works fine
from requests_html import HTMLSession

url = 'https://opensea.io/rankings'

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)

collections = r.html.find('#main > div > div.sc-1xf18x6-0.enKNee > div > div:nth-child(3)')
print(collections)
```

the difference between the two is whether the CSS selector contains the last div

```
# this one works fine
from requests_html import HTMLSession

url = 'https://opensea.io/rankings'

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)
collections = r.html.find('#main > div > div.sc-1xf18x6-0.enKNee > div > div:nth-child(3) > div')
print(collections)
```

thank you

Comment: Why is this tagged `dd`?

Comment: I recommend using requests and BeautifulSoup for scraping

Comment: @SYNEC I changed it to BeautifulSoup and it's working thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### I got all 100 data using this code.

```
search_url = 'https://opensea.io/rankings'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=f"C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(search_url)  
driver.maximize_window()

def RemoveExtraSpace(string):
    new = ' '.join(string.split())
    return newp = 1

while True:
    try:
        ele = WebDriverWait(driver, 4).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f'//div[text()="{p}"]'))).find_element(By.XPATH, '..').find_element(By.XPATH, '..').find_element(By.XPATH, '..').find_element(By.XPATH, '..')
        print(RemoveExtraSpace(ele.text))
        p+=1
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, arguments[0]);", 85)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        driver.quit()
        break
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).